# Using Regular expression to match

Tags: python

I wish to find a symbol '$' present in my string.

```
s= 'abc$efg'
import re
result = re.match(r'\$',s)
```

I want to write a if statement which gives me an error when a $ is present , else prints OK!!

```
 if '$ available in result':
   print 'error'
 else:
   print 'OK'
```

I want to achieve this using regular expression rather than a simple way as below:

```
res = str.find('$')
  if  res!=-1:
   print 'error'
```

Comment: Have you tried this yourself yet and ran into difficulty? Why would you want to use a regex for this problem when a simpler way is available?

Comment: `re.match` will only match if the pattern matches at the BEGINNING of the string; use `re.search` with your pattern and you are closer.

Comment: got it!!! I dint know I can do this by re.search. what would be a good example to understand re.match? How to use the result obtained from re.match?

Comment: You would use `re.match` for an anchored string like `re.match(r'(\d+)', "1234abc")` That matches digits only if they are at the start of the string. To do the same thing with search, you would do `re.search(r'^(\d+)', "1234abc")` which are functionally similar but different implementations. To get only the letters: `re.match(r'\d+(\w+)', "1234abc")` or `re.match(r'\W+(\w+)', "1234abc")` vs `re.search(r'(\w+)', "1234abc")`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, would be using the `in` operator:

```
if '$' in my_string:
    print('Error')
```

Using regular expressions is a lot less efficient and slower:

```
if re.search('\$', my_string):
    print('Error')
```

Answer (score 1):

While it seems pointless to look for a more complicated way to do this, when you yourself have demonstrated the find method, and using the in operator, like:

```
>>> '$' in s
True
```

would be nicer too.

`re.match` only looks for a match at the very start of a string. However,

You could try this:

```
s= 'abc$efg'

import re

if re.search(r'\$', s): # re.search looks for matches throughout the string
    print 'error' # raise Error might be more what you want
else:
    print 'ok'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s = 'abc$efg'

if re.search('\$', s):  # Returns true if any instance is found.
    raise Error
else:
    print 'OK'
```

We have to use the escape character `\` on `$` because `$` is a special character in `re`, but we just want to find that character and not use it as an operand.